# What are methods for migrating from one technology to another?

Tags: php, django, zend-framework

I'm working on a project using Zend Framework, which I initially chose since I had a bit more experience in it. At this point in time, I'm thinking of moving to Django, though, as our current team will be more productive in it.

I'm trying to figure out the best way to (potentially) go about this, as we evaluate it. A lot of our code is still fairly fluid, and being re-written fairly often. The way I had considered is that as something ends up being re-done, redo it in Django, and change my PHP model to simply be a call to the Django underbelly and translation to PHP. Over time, we should have all of the models, at least, in Django.

Are there better ways? Particularly, is there any way to easily manage having two codebases at once?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no generic answer to cross-language migration projects.

If you can wrap your php code and hide it behind web services, you will be on a good path because you will be able to migrate those web services later without changing the API.

Make a list of the main components of your architecture and try to see which ones could be hidden behind such a web service API.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that if your web app is db driven, move your business logic to your db and have your data mappers call db stored procedures. I'm developing using ZF myself, which is a very strong tool, but the immense 'abstracticity' it offers can deviate you from your goals... Then you can mess as much as you like with your controllers and views...